# Nginx lua log location

Tags: nginx, lua

The Nginx lua module has a [logging method](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxlog):

```
 ngx.log(ngx.NOTICE, "hello world")
```

However, the docs don't indicate where this is logged to. Does it depend on the level param, ie ngx.ERROR would be in error log, while ngx.NOTICE would be in access log? Or some other file that needs to be configured?

I've added a log with `ngx.INFO` and not seeing anything appear in the logs folder.

Comment: It outputs to nginx log based on [this issue](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/issues/467).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says exactly the next line:

> Log arguments concatenated to error.log with the given logging level.

You should be looking into nginx's `error.log`. It's configured using nginx conf:

```
// example
error_log  logs/error.log error;
```

Comment: I thought error.log was meant as a global file handle or something, as I'm not seeing them there for some reason (I was tailing *.log). I think it's because of what's mentioned in https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/issues/467 which is that INFO level won't show up there by default.